# Me da error al intentar registrar una nueva persona (artista) en Java

Tags: java

Buenas a todos, estoy realizando un programa en Java en el cual debo registrar artistas, y también sus Albumes y Canciones (bueno, y también modificación y eliminación pero eso no viene ahora al caso).

Todo está conectado a una Base de Datos de MySql, el programa me solicita el nombre nada mas, os pongo los metodos que tengo para ello:

Esta es la clase Conexión, donde realizo la conexión a la BD:

```
public class Conexion {

private static Connection conexion=null;

/*Conectamos a la Base de Datos*/

public Conexion(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/chinook", "root", "");

        String alterIdArtista="ALTER TABLE artist MODIFY COLUMN ArtistId INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY";
        Statement sqlAlterArtista = conexion.createStatement();
        sqlAlterArtista.executeUpdate(alterIdArtista);

        sqlAlterArtista.close();
    }catch(Exception excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*Devolvemos la conexion*/

public static Connection abrir() {
    return conexion != null ? conexion : new Conexion().conexion;
}

public static boolean cerrar() {
    try {
        conexion.close();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception excepcion) {
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}
De la clase donde tengo los metodos de registro:

```
 public void addArtista(ArtistaVO artistaVO){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();

    try{
        //Insertamos los datos del Artista
        PreparedStatement  sqlAddArtist=conexion.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT into artist values(?,?)");
        ResultSet resultado=sqlAddArtist.executeQuery();
        while(resultado.next()){
            sqlAddArtist.setString(1, artistaVO.getNombreArtista());
            sqlAddArtist.setInt(2, getMaxId()+1);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha añadido exitosamente","Información",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        sqlAddArtist.close();
        conexion.desconectar();

    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        System.out.println(excepcion.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se registro", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Este es el metodo que uso para obtener la Id del Artista:

```
  public int getMaxId(){
    int id=0;
    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();

    try{
        Statement sqlMaxId=conexion.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultado=sqlMaxId.executeQuery("SELECT max(ArtistId) from artist");

        if(resultado.next()){
            id=resultado.getInt(0);
        }

        conexion.desconectar();
        sqlMaxId.close();
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        System.out.println(excepcion.getMessage());
    }

    return id;
}
```

Y este es que está en la clase de la ventana de añadir el artista, para que al pulsar el botón se registre:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {

    if(evento.getSource()==botonAñadir){

        try{
            ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO();
            artistaVO.setNombreArtista(campoTextoArtista.getText());

            miCoordinador.addArtista(artistaVO);
        }catch(Exception excepcion){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al añadir Artista", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

El error que me salta es el de "Error al añadir Artista", asi que estoy totalmente perdido en donde puede estar el fallo, y seguramente sea una tontería pero estoy bloqueado.

Esta es la excepcion que me arroja

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at controlador.Coordinador.addArtista(Coordinador.java:108)
at vista.VistaArtistasAdd.actionPerformed(VistaArtistasAdd.java:70)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Añado esto porque es donde me muestra la excepcion que apunta NullPointerException

```
public void validarRegistroArtista(ArtistaVO artistaVO){
    ArtistaDAO artistaDAO;

    if(artistaVO.getIdArtista()>0){
        artistaDAO=new ArtistaDAO();
        artistaDAO.addArtista(artistaVO);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe de introducirse algún numero de ID", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
  }
```

Comment: escribir 'excepcion.printStackTrace(); en 'actionPerformed'. Y publicar la salida aqui

Comment: He añadido la excepción que me arroja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código es incorrecto

```
public void addArtista(ArtistaVO artistaVO){

  Conexion conexion=new Conexion();

  try {
    //Insertamos los datos del Artista
    PreparedStatement  sqlAddArtist=conexion.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT into artist values(?,?)");
    //Cargamos los valores en el preparestatement, las ? se sustituyen por
    //valor real
    sqlAddArtist.setString(1, artistaVO.getNombreArtista());
    sqlAddArtist.setInt(2, getMaxId()+1);

    //ejecutas la query 
    ResultSet resultado=sqlAddArtist.executeQuery();

    //Creas una lista de entidades vacias
    List<ArtistaVO> resultados=new ArrayList<ArtistaVO>();

    //recores el resultado, creando las entidades y cargandolas en su lista
    while(resultado.next()){
        //creas entidad
        ArtistaVO entidad=new ArtistaVO();
        //cargas valores resultado en entidad
        entidad.setNombreArtista(resultado.getString(1));
        entidad.setMaxId(resultado.getInt(2));
        //añades a la lista de entidades
        resultados.add(entidad);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha añadido exitosamente","Información",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    sqlAddArtist.close();
    conexion.desconectar();

  } catch(SQLException excepcion){
      System.out.println(excepcion.getMessage());
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se registro", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Para generar ids en Mysql puedes definir la *primary key* de la tabla como *autoincrement* esto hará que cada vez que añadas un registro en la tabla se generara el id siguiente, y así tu no te tienes que preocupar de este tema. Me da que es posible que el código que tienes no sea correcto por como gestionas tu este problema mas alla de los cambios que te he marcado yo.

Comment: Me sigue dando error, y seguramente sea posible por lo que dices, pero no he trabajado mucho con SQL en Java, este es mi primer proyecto "serio" con SQL en Java, así que no tengo claro como añadir el autoincrement y menos aun, modificar el código de de addArtista para que coja lo del autoincrement.

Answer (score 2):

Debes de realizar cambios en como tratas el ID de artista y corregir la llamada a ejecutar la sentencia ya que es una actualización lo que realizas (insert, update, delete) y no una lectura (select). Te dejo a continuación los pasos a seguir detallados:

## ACTUALIZACIÓN CON MALAS PRÁCTICAS

Debido al requerimiento de no poder alterar la tabla desde la base de datos, vamos a alterarla, desde Java.

Crea algún método que solo será ejecutado una vez, lo llamaremos: establecerAutoIncrementATablaArtista().

```
void establecerAutoIncrementATablaArtista() {
    Statement st = Conexion.abrir().createStatement();
    final String consultaSQL = "ALTER TABLE artista MODIFIY id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    st.execute(consultaSQL);
    Conexion.cerrar();
}
```

> Paso 1: Modificar tabla

Para ahorrarte la lógica de negocio por el campo ID de ArtistoVO en Java yo añadiría a la tabla de MySQL que ese campo ID (supongo que PRIMARY KEY) sea también AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
ALTER TABLE artista MODIFY id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

> Paso 2: Refactorizar código no necesario tras la la adaptación del paso 1.

Método getMaxId() fuera y la clase ArtistaVo, el setId(int) también fuera.

> Paso 2.5: Propuesta de utilizar el patrón singleton para tu clase Conexión.

Es muy mejorable el siguiente código, pero es para que te hagas una idea.

```
public final class Conexion {

// CAMPOS

private static Connection conexion = null;

// CONSTRUCTOR

private Conexion() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/chinook", "root", "");
    } catch(Exception excepcion) {
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// MÉTODOS

public static Connection abrir() {
    return conexion != null ? conexion : new Conexion().conexion;
}

public static boolean cerrar() {
    try {
        conexion.close();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception excepcion) {
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}    

}
```

> Paso 3: Realizar correctamente el prepared statement parametrizado.

En tu código llamabas a executeQuery() para obtener el ResultSet sin antes darle los parámetros que necesitaba en tu consulta:

```
INSERT INTO artista VALUES (?,?);
```

Para corregirlo debes de introducir los parámetros antes de llamar a executeUpdate(), ya que es una consulta de actualización, y como hemos modificado la tabla, la consulta sería esta:

```
INSERT INTO artista VALUES (NULL,?); // o bien... INSERT INTO artista (nombre) VALUES (?);
```

El código te quedaría así:

```
public void addArtista(ArtistaVO artistaVO){

try {

    // Se prepara consulta parametrizada
    final String consultaSQL = "INSERT INTO artist values(NULL, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = Conexion.abrir().prepareStatement(consultaSQL);
    ps.setString(1, artistaVO.getNombreArtista());

    // Se obtienen resultados.
    Integer filasAfectadas = ps.executeUpdate(); // 1 es correcto.

    // Compruebas resultado.

    if (filasAfectadas == 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OK, inserción correcta,", "OK Message",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "KO, inserción incorrecta.", "KO Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    ps.close(); // Cierras PreparedStatement
    Conexion.cerrar(); //

} catch(SQLException excepcion) {
    System.out.println(excepcion.getMessage());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "KO, ha ocurrido algún error al insertar.", "KO Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

}
```

Comment: He hecho los cambios como me has indicado, en Conexion he añadido lo del autoincrement porque no debo hacerlo en la propia base de datos, cualquier cambio en la base de datos debe ser que lo haga el programa, así nos lo han pedido en clase.

También he añadido el método que parece que es el que da error, pero no se si es correcto o no.

Comment: Entonces prueba en realizar el ALTER TABLE para el AUTO_INCREMENT desde Java, te he actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Negativo. Muchas malas prácticas involucradas.

Comment: Esta respuesta es terrible, me asusta ver tantas sentencias de SQL en el código. Ataques de SQL a al vista.

Comment: Entonces, ¿cómo podría realizar el `autoincrement` desde Java?